# Redux mapDispatchToProps method is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm calling method `this.props.addItemToCart(elem.id)` in order to add an `id` value to the redux store, but it is not working. No values are being added.
Here's a [link to `container` `reducer` and an `action_creator` code.](https://gist.github.com/Y-Taras/be0777006e925a9d80e367221a481caf)
Small abstracts, that are related to the question I show here:

```
   ...
  <Button onClick={() => this.props.addItemToCart(elem.id)}>
              Add to Cart
  </Button>
```

....

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getAPIData() {
    dispatch(....,
  addItemToCart(value) {
    dispatch(addToCart(value));
  },
  removeItemFromCart(value) {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(value));
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductsList);
```

Here's a part of reducer's code:

```
const handleCart = (state = initialState.addedIds, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      if (state.indexOf(action.productId) !== -1) {
        return state
      }
      return [...state, action.productId];
    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      return state.filter(productId => action.productId !== productId);
    default:
      return state
  }

};
```

Comment: You should include the full code for the `Button` component. Are you sure `this.props` refer to the passed in props? Is this in the `render` method of a class component?

Comment: yes I checked using console log in method and it's passing a value to the console

Comment: You code is not a [mcve]. So it's not possible to answer your question.

Comment: In the third sentence - there's a link to the full code without any shortening. I thought it would not be convinient to read all the code Here.

Comment: Relevant code must be included in the question itself. You haven't bound `this` to your custom methods, such as `renderProductsList`. The scoping rules for `this` can be confusing. In the default lifecycle methods, such as `render`,  `this` is already bound.

Comment: I use babel-plugin-transform-class-properties to do autobinding for me

Comment: All question seeking debugging help should contain a complete example.  See the linked document:  "**Complete**

Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included:

Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try them to test the answer they're about to post.
The problem might not be in the part you suspect it is, but another part entirely."

Comment: Well, do you mean I should give a link of all the app on the github?

Comment: @HåkenLid the thing is that my circumstanses force me to find a bug as soon as possible, cause it's an test task for a job, and I promiced to send the code today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action creator does not create the `productId` property on the action, so this will always be `undefined`.

```
  if (state.indexOf(action.productId) !== -1) {
```

Read your own code (which you didn't include in the question). You put the product id value in `action.payload`. So, try to change the reducer code accordingly.

```
  if (state.indexOf(action.payload) !== -1) {
```

Comment: There might be other bugs in your code as well. I have not run it, and since some functionality relies on unknown babel plugins such as `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`, it's not possible to reproduce without an identical build environment.

Comment: babel-plugin-transform-class-properties - it's stage 2 of  TC39 proposals. And thank you for an excelent help. This proposal  Got stuck at this stage second year

Answer (score 0):

The way you are writing `mapDispatchToProps` is wrong. It should be something like this.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        addItemToCart: bindActionCreators(addToCart, dispatch),
        // Other actions should go here ...
    };
}
```

Then it will bind your action to the props, hence the action can be invoked using,

```
this.props.addItemToCart(values);
```

Finally pass it to the connect helper like this.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductsList);
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding !

Comment: Ir's weird because all other methods are working fine. BTW the style  I'm writing mapdispatchtoprops I took from FrontendMasters Course = Complete intro to React V3 https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-react/

Comment: He's using ES2015 method shorthand syntax. It's not the common way to do it, but it should give the same results as your answer.

Comment: try this one and see how it goes. If not you have to log in different places and see where the error is.